# How to create array of Form Group

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular9

Below is my JSON object. I have to create a reactive form with respect to this. What should I do specially for the array part ?

```
{
    "examName" : "java",
    "password" : "1234.com",
    "examCategory" : {
        "id" : 78
    },
    "examDetailSet" : 
        [ 
            {
                "questionCategory" : {"id" : 40},
                "section" : {"id" : 7},
                "numberOfQuestions" : 3
            },
            {
                "questionCategory" : {"id" : 41},
                "section" : {"id" : 8},
                "numberOfQuestions" : 6
            }
        ],
    "expiryHours" : 6
}
```

**abc.component.ts**

```
// The formGroup I have created
formdata = this.fb.group({
    examName: ['', Validators.required], password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
    examCategory: this.fb.group({
      id: [0, Validators.required]
    }),
    examDetailSet: new FormArray([
      new FormGroup({
        questionCategory: this.fb.group({
          id: [0, Validators.required]
        }),
        section: this.fb.group({
          id: [0, Validators.required]
        }),
        numberOfQuestions: new FormControl(['', Validators.required])
      })
    ]),
    expiryHours: [0, Validators.required]
});
```

**abc.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="formdata" (submit)="onSubmit()">
  <mat-dialog-content>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <mat-form-field appearance="legacy" class="example-full-width">
          <mat-label>Exam Name</mat-label>
          <input matInput formControlName="examName">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <mat-form-field appearance="legacy" class="example-full-width">
          <mat-label>Exam Password</mat-label>
          <input matInput [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'" formControlName="password">
          <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide" [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'"
            [attr.aria-pressed]="hide">
            <mat-icon>{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6" formGroupName="examCategory">
        <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
          <mat-label>Exam Category</mat-label>
          <mat-select formControlName="id">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let e of ExamCategory" [value]="e.id">{{ e.examCategoryName }}</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h2 class="d-flex justify-content-center">Exam Details</h2>
    <span formArrayName="examDetailSet">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" formGroupName="questionCategory">
          <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
            <mat-label>Question Category</mat-label>
            <mat-select formControlName="id">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let e of QuestionCategory" [value]="e.id">{{ e.questionCategoryName }}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" formGroupName="section">
          <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
            <mat-label>Section Marks</mat-label>
            <mat-select formControlName="id">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let e of Marks" [value]="e.id">{{ e.marksPerQuestion }}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
    </span>
    <div class="row">
      <span formArrayName="examDetailSet">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <mat-form-field appearance="legacy" class="example-full-width">
            <mat-label>Number of Questions</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="numberOfQuestions">
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </span>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <mat-form-field appearance="legacy" class="example-full-width">
          <mat-label>Expiry Hours</mat-label>
          <input matInput formControlName="expiryHours">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-dialog-content>
  <mat-dialog-actions>
    <button type="submit" mat-flat-button color="primary" mat-dialog-close [disabled]="formdata.invalid">Add</button>
    <button mat-flat-button color="warn" mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
  </mat-dialog-actions>
</form>
```

So this is my code I've made till now but now it's telling that can't find the control with the path in `examDetailSet` and it's controls. Below is the screenshot:
[image]

I've created this by following the link given in answer below.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

when you has an FormArray, you not only need use formArrayName else you need iterate over controls, see the `*ngFor` in the code

```
<span formArrayName="examDetailSet">
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let group of formdata.get('examDetailSet').controls;let i=index"
     [formGroupName]="i">
    <div class="col-md-6" formGroupName="questionCategory">
    ....
</span>
```

It's better create getters to the formArray, to has no problem with "type errors"

```
get examDetailArray()
{
    return this.formdata.get('examDetailSet') as FormArray
}
```

And use in the *ngFor

```
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let group of examDetailArray.controls;let i=index"
     [formGroupName]="i">
```

NOTE: You can use also  `[formGroup]="group"` (group is the variable used in the `*ngFor`) instead of `[formGroupName]="i"`

**Update** how create a FormGroup and a formArray when we has an object

A tell this some more time. The ideal is has two functions, one to create the form and want to create the formArray

```
createForm(data:any)
{
    //if we has no data create "ad hoc" an object by defect
    data=data || {examName:null,
                  password:null,
                  examCategory : {
                    id:0
                 },
                 examDetailSet:null //<--see that the array is null
                 expiryHours:0
             } 
    return this.fb.group({
    examName: [data.examName, Validators.required], 
    password: [data.passwrod, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
    examCategory: this.fb.group({
      id: [data.examCategory.id, Validators.required]
    }),
    examDetailSet: new FormArray(
      data.examDetailSet==null?this.createGroup(null):
                               data.examDetailSet.map(x=>this.createGroup(x)
    )
    section: this.fb.group({
          id: [data.section.id, Validators.required]
        }),
    numberOfQuestions: [data.numberOfQuestion, Validators.required],
    expiryHours: [data.expiryHours, Validators.required]
});
 }

createGroup(data)
{
   data=data || {
                questionCategory:
                  {id : 0},
                section : {id : 0},
                numberOfQuestions" : 0
            }
  return this.fb.group({
        questionCategory: this.fb.group({
          id: [data.questionCategory.id, Validators.required]
        }),
        section: this.fb.group({
          id: [data.section.id, Validators.required]
        }),
        numberOfQuestions: [data.numberOfQuestion, Validators.required]
      })
}
```

See how if we has an object we create the formArray using "map". Each element of the array is converted in a formGroup. Your Form can be create simply

```
formData=this.createForm(null)
//or if you has data
formData=this.createForm(myObject)
```

If you want to add an element to the array use

```
(formData.get('examDetailSet') as FormArray.push(this.createGroup(null))
```

Comment: and what about the typescript side ? Is that perfect what I've created according to my JSON data ?

Comment: @AVISHEKDATTARAY, sorry, I don't check the typeScript. I updated the answer. BTW choose use formBuilder or directly new FormArray, new FormControl and new FormGroup

Answer (score 0):

You can use FormArray. Just like a FormGroup, which groups AbstractControl objects in an object, a FormArray does the same but in an array.

You can refer below link for an example - 
https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a

Comment: I've updated my question by following your link but getting a error. Please help me to sort it out.